# Automatic, intelligent correction of input text field to positive integer

Tags: jquery, validation

Apologies if this has been asked before, I have not found any previous questions that ask this satisfactorily comprehensively, or answers that cover it.

I want a client-side javascript (or JQuery) solution that forces users to use a whole number in an input field. (For quantity of an item in a shopping basket: when adding items on a product page, and when reviewing the basket before checkout).

Perhaps in order of difficulty, the requirements are:

- Only accept characters 0-9.
- Allow cutting-and-pasting, across browsers and OS's, by key shortcuts and/or right-click menus etc
- Allow entry via other methods (Are there other ways a number can be entered?)
- Allow the user to delete all characters before entering in a new value (While preventing an empty value at some stage, e.g. when losing focus

In short, I want this to be perfectly designed. Obviously I will have server-side code to check for validity, but I want to focus on usability.

This is the procedure I have in mind, but would like issues to be raised about potential pitfalls, and so on, comprehensively covering the use-cases.

The client-side algorithm could be split into two three chunks: validate/filter on keypress, validate/filter on de-focus, validate/filter on submit.

Firstly, are there any native functions in JQuery that do this for me? If not, how does the following algorithm sound?

1. On key press, and on change: Remove characters not in range 0-9. Then check that contents consists either of empty string, or parseable into a positive integer. (This will allow cut-and-paste). But what if it is not parseable? I don't want to reinvent the wheel in terms of envisaging the myriad of use-cases.
2. On loss of focus or on submit, perform the above check. (In an identical fashion, except converting empty string to zero)

My concerns are how this would affect usability with devices such as smart TVs, smartphones and tablets, accessibility tools, and everything else.

In short, my question is: **are there ways I can avoid re-inventing the wheel here? Has this problem been thoroughly solved, and up-to-date, somewhere? Am I blowing this whole thing out of proportion?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is one that is faced by a lot of people, but I don't know of any standard solution for the same. Having said that, I guess you're still blowing things out of proportion.(Ideally you should not change anything the user types, you should tell him that its wrong, but not change it automatically). Now, all you need is use HTML5 validations using regular expressions. If the user enters something that does not satisfy the RegEx, an error message will be displayed next to the textbox, and he shouldn't be allowed to proceed until he solves the issue. This way, the same RegEx can be used to handle all your cases, like whole number, non empty textbox etc. Eg: /^[+]?([0-9]+)$/ can be used for positive numbers. You can implement the same using javascript too.